# How can I view the history of a source file from apt-get source?

Tags: apt, source

It seems I cannot find the answer to that one as easily as I have hoped.
I have a package, and I suspect a change in one of the conf broke something in my tests.

For example, how can I get see the changes done on the file `/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties` from the package `libapache2-mod-jk`?

What I am aiming for is the equivalent of git blame on files contained in a package.

Answer (score 0):

From reading `man apt-get`, you could use the `source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...` syntax to install the versions you want, then use recursive `diff`. See `man apt-get;man diff`

Comment: I was more looking for a way to determine that for a specific line, retrieve the last version that changed it.